# TeamViewer log files location

Tags: macos, teamviewer, logfiles

I want to access my office computer with TeamViewer, but the ID that I usually use is gone because of a fresh installation. I have SSH access to the office machine, but I don't know where the log files containing the ID are located on a Mac OS X. Are they always in the same place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a more easy solution is to just read the TeamViewer plist, e.g.

```
# defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist ClientID
```

(the above plist file is for TeamViewer 8, just change it to match your version)

If "defaults" fails try (e.g on OSX 10.6):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ClientID" /Library/Preferences/com.TeamViewer8.Settings.plist
```

Anyway logs are found under ~/Library/Logs/TeamViewer/

Comment: Better late than never. I ended up getting what I needed in another way, but I checked your answer and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Might be a little bit too late - but to whom it may concern:

If the above does not work for you:

Start System Utility "Console.app" (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app) and look at Files -> ~/Library/Logs/TeamViewer where you should find a Connections.txt as well as TeamViewerX_Logfile.log (whereas X stands for your TeamViewer version).

Even if you used many different TeamViewer versions in the past, the logfiles will still be there at one place!

Comment: In mine (TeamViewer11 and prior versions) I found the relevant log in `/Library/Logs/TeamViewer/Connections_incoming.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This [TeamViewer community knowledgebase answer](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-find-your-log-files-on-Windows-and-Mac-and-Linux/ta-p/4694#) explains how to access the logs using Windows, Mac or Linux.